# How to iterate json consists of array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, iteration

I am getting this object :

```
"contributionData": {
        "Contribution 1": [
            4,
            4
        ],
        "Contribution 2": [
            1,
            1
        ]
    }
```

I want this kind of table after iteration.

```
contribution1 |  4  |  4  |
contribution2 |  1  |  1  |
```

I've converted it to array :

```
        let result = [];

        for(let i in this.state.testData) {
            result.push([i, this.state.testData[i]]);
        }
```

[console log after converting it to array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OGOI.png)

```
   <tr>
       <td>{this.state.result}</td>
   </tr>
```

I want to fill this data in table format
I am working on React js, I want to do this in javascript.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: pls show your attempt

Comment: I can' t see any difference, post jon you want pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
let result = []
let data = {
  "Contribution 1": [
            4,
            4
        ],
        "Contribution 2": [
            1,
            1
        ]
}
Object.keys(data).map((item) => {result.push([item].concat(data[item]))})
console.log(result);
...
{
    results.map(item, i)=> (
      <tr key={i}>
          {item.map(val, index) => (
            <td key={"row" + index}>{val}</td>
          )}
      </tr>
    )
}
```

Comment: How can I fill this data in table ? Can you write map function of js for this

Comment: I updated the answer. Take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Comment: It's my pleasure.